# How to initialize array of struct that have a pointer to array of struct?

Tags: c, c99

This is my struct:

```c
struct ini_entry {
    const char *section;
    const char *name;
};

struct ini_parser {
    bool (*parser) (void *ctx, const char *file, struct collection_item **vals, int nval);
    struct ini_entry *entries;
};
```

This is my initializer:

```c
static struct ini_parser parsers[] = {
    {NULL, &(struct ini_entry) {"test", "xxx"}}
};
```

I need to add more `ini_entry` in the initializer. Is there anyway to do this with static initialization within a single declaration?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `struct ini_entry *entries;` should be `struct ini_entry const *entries;` if you intend to initialize it with a struct literal (and even if you don't).

But this sort of layout may be easier to read:

```
struct ini_entry const foo_entries[] = {
    { "test", "xxx" },
    { "flub", "yyy" },
    { "gnas", "zzz" },
    { NULL, NULL }     // list terminator presumably required
};

struct ini_parser const parsers[] = {
    { "foo", foo_entries },
    { "bar", bar_entries }
};
```

Note that it would be possible to use a counted list instead of using an end sentry; the length of the list is a compile-time constant `(sizeof foo_entries / sizeof foo_entries[0])` which you could put as a third member of `struct ini_parser`.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I need a single declaration without dedicated `ini_entry`. Somethings like this `{NULL, &(struct ini_entry) {{"test", "xxx"}, {"test2", "yyy"}}}`.

Comment: why do you "need" that?

Comment: I think it is easy to use than create a new dedicated array of `ini_entry`. It also remove a variable that only used to initialize the struct.

Comment: got a better idea? :)  There's no problem with having variables that are only used in one place. IMO this is much easier to read than pages full of struct literal casts (even if that version is possible)

Comment: The problems is array of `ini_parser` can have so many elements. That mean I have to create the variables to initialize each element equal to the length of `ini_parser` array. Sorry for my horrible requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the length "issue" remains whether you use my version or an all-in-one version , and it's really a non-issue because it is simple to deal with, as my answer describes.

Comment: All I need to do is define a parser for INI. Each element of `ini_parser` will have a function to process the values of INI entries that specified in the `entries`. I need a multiple `entries` because some configuration need a multiple INI's entry to construct.

Comment: That's fine, my suggestion features multiple entries

Comment: Yes, your suggestion solved my problems. But I am perfectionist. This make I hate my self in sometime when facing the problems that no perfect solution. Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Perfection is in the eye of the beholder... I've come to appreciate clarity and simplicity, over time